# showing "processing" while process request is working

Tags: javascript, ihttphandler

I just wrote a IhttpHandler in ashx page and I´m making a call from a javascript function like this:

```
function obtenerFichero(id) {
    document.getElementById('<%= proces.ClientID %>').style.visibility = "visible";
    window.location.href = '../HELPDESK/DescargaFichero.ashx?ID=' + id;
}
```

Everything is fine but the request takes a very long time to complete and I would like to show a div with a "Processing" message, and hide it once the request is complete

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you want is impossible. What can be done instead is loading the page in an invisible iframe. When loading is complete, we can set the html of the 'main' page to that of the iframe. Till then, we can show a 'loading' animation.

Comment: I´ve read many articles on how to implement a real progress bar in asp.net but it´s still confusing to me what is the best approach: threads..httphandlers..async calls..